# Java/Android : First tiny app answer always "false"

Tags: java, android

*I try to create my first tiny app but i have a problem*.

My tiny math app always say my answer is false.I don't understand why.

This is my first app, i don't know where i'm wrong.

```
private TextView problem;
private EditText question;
private Button button;
private TextView reponse;
private int aleatoire = new Random().nextInt(61) + 20;
private int aleatoire2 = new Random().nextInt(48) + 20;
private int result = aleatoire + aleatoire2;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    problem = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.problem);
    question = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
    button   = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    reponse = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.resultat);

    problem.setText("Result = "+aleatoire+"+"+aleatoire2);



    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String str=question.getText().toString();

            if (str.equals(result)) {
                reponse.setText("True !");
            } else {
                reponse.setText("False !");
            }
        }
    });
```

**Answer always "False"**

*I'm a new student in the dev world*.

Comment: A `String` is *never* going to be `equals()` to an `int`.  You need to convert one to the same type as the other, and then compare them.

Comment: You need to convert the String to Integer, you can use `int strx=Integer.parseInt(str);` before comparing it

Answer (score 2):

The problem with code is that you are comparing string with integer, that's  why it always returns false as java is strictly typed language.

problem code:

```
   if(str.equals(result)){...}
```

possible solutions:

```
 if( str.equals(""+result)){...}
```

or

```
str.equals(String.valueof(result)) // best solution
```

or

```
if(result==Integer.parseInt(str)){...}
```

Here is corrected code:

```
private TextView problem;
private EditText question;
private Button button;
private TextView reponse;
private int aleatoire = new Random().nextInt(61) + 20;
private int aleatoire2 = new Random().nextInt(48) + 20;
private int result = aleatoire + aleatoire2;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

     problem = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.problem);
    question = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
    button   = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    reponse = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.resultat);

    problem.setText("Result = "+aleatoire+"+"+aleatoire2);



    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


    @Override
 public void onClick(View v) {
        String str=question.getText().toString();

        if (str.equals(""+result)) {
            reponse.setText("True !");
        } else {
            reponse.setText("False !");
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As azurefrog comment says, you're comparing a **String** to an **int**. You will need to transform `str` to an `int` or `result` to a `String`. You can for example do:

```
String str=question.getText().toString();

        if (str.equals(String.valueOf(result))) {
            reponse.setText("True !");
        } else {
            reponse.setText("False !");
        }
```